# how to make outer for loop to work for inner for loop in java

Tags: java

I have a below class named broker invoice so as shown below
broker invoice class has an member variable which return type is of array

```
public class BrokerInvoice
{

private BrokerInvoiceLineItem[] lineItemsView;

}


public class BrokerInvoiceLineItem
{
}
```

now below is the piece where i am manipulating as shown that is i am reading an single tab excel sheet and populating all thing in  brokerInvoice objects and then later on fetching the value of BrokerInvoiceLineItem

```
 brokerInvoice = readinginvoiceimpl.findHeaderRowNumber(workbookXls, 0, brokerInvoiceLineItemList, brokerInvoice , brokerIdLong , finalfilteredfilename,dateType );


for (BrokerInvoiceLineItem item : brokerInvoice
                                .getLineItems()) {

                            if (item.getreaddeate() == null) {

                                throw new BOARuntimeException(
                                        "readdeate is not there" );
                            }
```

now the issue comes if i am reading the multiple tab delimeted excel sheets where each tab data is associaoted with brokerInvoice objects so finally i am adding them in a seprate list named totalbrokerinvoiceobjects

```
  //Reading multitabs sheets from excel workbook
            for (int i = 0; i < workbookXls.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> brokerInvoiceLineItemList = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();
            brokerInvoice = readinginvoiceimpl.findHeaderRowNumber(workbookXls, 0, brokerInvoiceLineItemList, brokerInvoice , brokerIdLong , finalfilteredfilename,dateType );
            totalBrokerInvoiceObjects.add(brokerInvoice);
            }
```

now all the broker invoice objects are in list named  totalBrokerInvoiceObjects now please advise how can i perfor a check for each brokerInvoice object as i have to check this now  `brokerInvoice.getLineItems())`  for all broker invoice object in the list named totalBrokerInvoiceObjects

Shall I start outer for loop first which will fetch each broker invoice object first and then on that brokerInvoice object to check get line items as I use to do earlier

Comment: What error are you getting? Please take the time to improve your grammar.

Comment: Sure will do I am not getting an error please advise inside list totalbrokerinvoiceobjects which inside contain brokerinvoiceobjects  how I will check for get line items as I use to do earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to move the `List` instantiation outside of the `outer` loop and use `addAll` to combine everything into one list:

```
List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> brokerInvoiceLineItemList = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < workbookXls.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
    brokerInvoice = readinginvoiceimpl.findHeaderRowNumber(workbookXls, 0, brokerInvoiceLineItemList, brokerInvoice , brokerIdLong , finalfilteredfilename,dateType );
    for (BrokerInvoiceLineItem item : brokerInvoice.getLineItems()) {
        if (item.getreaddeate() == null) {
            throw new BOARuntimeException("readdeate is not there" );
        }
    }
    totalBrokerInvoiceObjects.addAll(brokerInvoice.getLineItems());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas so in this way we have added all brokerInvoice objects line items explicitly but how we will track which line item belong to which broker invoice object

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well  I am trying to fetch all the line items correspond to broker invoice object and if any line items getrradddeate comes as null I will throw exception and also show that it's parent broker invoice object info also

Comment: You need to try something and then post a new question if you have any problems.